# Analogue encoder / multi-throw infinite-turn "potentiometer" from two-axis potentiometer/joystick

Tags: potentiometer

For an analogue multichannel audio-panner I essentially want to create something like an infinite-turn multi-throw potentiometer. The idea is to have one input which is distributed to 4-8 outputs through a resistor/opamp network where the "panning" is supposed to be continuous. You can imagine it like a surround panner where you can let a sound circle you if you have a symmetric speaker setup (ex octaphonic).

And I want it to be as cheap and simple a module as possible which is why I am avoiding VCAs/multipliers and try to route the audio signal directly through the panner instead of using it for control input only.

My current approach to be tested is based on using conductive materials (for now GRAPHIT 33, or a plastic-graphite mix) to create such an analogue "potentiometer" (because I did not find a ready-made component and for the fun of it) by creating a conductive ring or circle with evenly-spread taps/throws.

But my question here is more regarding an alternative:

Using a two-axis potentiometer (ie a joystick controller with two unconnected potentiometers placed in an 90 degree angle w.r.t. each other), is there a (simple) (linear) way to route (voltage) signals in a similar way as above mentioned approach would do? Ie, depending on position there would be an electrical connection to every (circular arranged) output but the further the output is from the input the higher the resistance which is something like a 2d potentiometer without separated axis.

Using the potentiometers as staged elements that distribute the signal to two outputs and then connecting this to another stage (with doubled amount of potentiometers) might some way or other work to single out individual outputs, but there problem is, there would be no "bleeding" to neighbouring outputs, but this does not seem very viable..

I am aware, using an encoder and digital potentiometers would be a plausible solution that would also allow for more possibilities (or panning/control behaviours) - but would need the necessary controller unit. I'm just curious if there is a simple solution using a (readymade) joystick..

ps. I'm afraid my electronics knowledge is rather rudimentary..

Comment: You'll need to figure out how you will create the logarithmic aural response when using linear potentiometers.

Comment: Hi! That's a valid input/concern that I did not consider yet, thanks! Possibly this could be resolved using VCAs even though that's not the plan, but I think given the requirements this can be neglected for the moment being (I feel like the encoder + digi-pot approach is the best anyways because it'd also allow automation and additional panning control) when thinking of the question only if and how a 2 axis pot could achieve similar output like a custom pot (which I find interesting in itself).